# Why is this volume mounted as read only?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I got from this link https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress a docker-compose.yml file like this.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

But the volume is not getting mounted on the wordpress folder, and if I delete "wordpress" to mount the volume on the local folder it gets mounted but it does as read only. I don't have a Dockerfile am I just using the default image and that's the problem?

Comment: So, I know that the reason is because the owner is www-data user and group, and I can change that with chown but I would like to avoid writing commands after creating the containers. And I know I can run commands in Dockerfile but I don't have any and I wuold prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: I've added more detail to my workflow answer incase you run into any issues 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use docker all the time for wordpress, this is my workflow.. (on a Mac)

Create a project folder and add a `docker-compose.yml` file with this..

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  # here is our mysql container
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # here is our wordpress container
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      DEVELOPMENT: 1
      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* Development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');

        /* Configure mailhog server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'whoever@example.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Whoever');

        /* other wp-config defines here */

  # here is our mailhog container
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
```

Then in this project folder run this terminal command (with docker app running)..

```
docker-compose up -d
```

..and bam you will have a wordpress site at `http://localhost/`

This `docker-compose.yml` is configured so you will have..

- Wordpress site at http://localhost/ or http://localhost:80
- Mailhog server that captures all outgoing mail at http://localhost:8025/
- Persistent local database, plugins, uploads and `uploads.ini`

All persistent data is mapped to this project folder, which is your theme folder. This keeps things nice and collected for each project..

[image]

After initial build before you do anything, replace the `uploads.ini` folder with an actual `uploads.ini` file..

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

So your project (theme) folder should look like this..

[image]

Now you can start building your theme in this folder like this, keeping everything associated with this local environment here.

[image]

Every time you run this command to shut down the environment..

```
docker-compose down
```

Next time you run this command on this project..

```
docker-compose up -d
```

..all your previous database, plugins and uploads will be exactly where you left off, awesome for wordpress local dev!

A few considerations to take into account..

---

### Using GIT with this local wordpress project

If your using GIT to save this project as a repository, then make sure your `.gitignore` file excludes these files/folders..

```
/vendor
/uploads
/db
/dist
/node_modules
/plugins
```

Worth having an alternate cloud backup solution setup like google drive for your `/db`, `/plugins` and `/uploads` folders, just in case of hard drive failure or something.

---

### Deploying to server, `staging` and `production`

In your IDE settings for this project you may want exclude certain files and folder from being deployed to `staging` and `production` server environments, this is what I normally exclude..

```
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/db
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/node_modules
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/src
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/uploads
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/composer.json
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/composer.lock
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/docker-compose.yml
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/package-lock.json
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/package.json
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/uploads.ini
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/webpack.mix.js
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/plugins
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/.gitignore
/Users/joshmoto/Sites/demo/vendor
```

- `/plugins` I manually manage by uploading through cPanel or wordpress dashboard, because the indexing is so heavy when syncing to remote.
- `/vendors` is generate from composer and the same problem, the indexing is crazy so best to manually zip this up and upload through cPanel or whatever server admin you use.

---

### If you have problems uploading media and plugins locally via the wordpress dashboard

You may be faced with some permission problems sometimes with dockers wordpress container `wp-content` folder. It is an easy fix. While your project is up and running in docker, in the project run these docker compose commands to change permissions on `wp-content` folder..

Show running docker containers command..

```
docker ps
```

Returned result..

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
4052536e574a        wordpress:latest         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   1 hour ago          Up 1 hour           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  demo_wordpress_1
b0fbb0a8f9e6        mysql:5.7                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   1 hour ago          Up 1 hour           0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   demo_db_1
769262e584e7        mailhog/mailhog:latest   "MailHog"                1 hour ago          Up 1 hour           1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp    demo_mailhog_1
```

Copy and take note the `wordpress:latest` container ID, in this example my container ID is..

```
4052536e574a
```

Now run this command using this wordpress container ID to execute stuff in this container directory..

```
docker exec -it 4052536e574a /bin/bash
```

Returned result..

```
root@4052536e574a:/var/www/html#
```

Now we are in the containers root directory you can now run this command which will change the permissions recursively on the `wp-content` and fix the uploading permissions issue in the local wordpress dashboard.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content
```

You may have to run `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` commands on the project folder for these changes to take effect but I don't think you need too.

---

### If you want a local custom URL instead of http://localhost

In terminal (not in your project folder this time) run this command to edit your hosts file..

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Then add your custom url to your hosts file via terminal and `WriteOut` before you `Exit`..

```
127.0.0.1  local.demo.com
```

Now your redirect mask is saved in your hosts you will need to add this to your `docker-compose.yml` below `/* other wp-config defines here */`..

```
define('WP_HOME','http://local.demo.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://local.demo.com');
```

Unfortunately you can't use `https`, you have to use `http`.

You will need to `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` for these newly define configs to run in your local `wp-config.php`.

---

### Handling your Staging and Production wp-config

Your server environments should be independently installed with unique salts etc, you **should not** take anything from the `docker-compose.yml` config, really you only want to add these extra defines initially..

**Staging** `wp-config.php`

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'staging');
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_HOME','https://staging.demo.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://staging.demo.com');
```

**Production** `wp-config.php`

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_HOME','https://www.demo.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.demo.com');
```

---

### Updating dockers wordpress image

You can't update your local wordpress site via the wordpress dashboard. In my `docker-compose.yml` example I am defining `image: wordpress:latest` which gets the latest wordpress image installed on your docker app.

This means if you `docker-compose up -d` on a project that was using an older version of wordpress at the time, this project would update to the latest wordpress image installed on docker.

I've not personally defined wordpress image versions in `docker-compose.yml` but you can if you do not want certain projects to use the latest image when you next `docker-compose up -d` a project.

You have to update the wordpress docker image manually using this command..

```
docker pull wordpress
```

And you will have to `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` for your project to use the latest update, which some times requires a wordpress database update when accessing the site for the first time through your browser.

---

### Permission issues when uploading / deleting plugins via dashboard

To change the permissions on the `wp-content` folder so `uploads` and `plugins` can be written via the dashboard.

Make sure you run these commands below while the containers are running...

1. Show containers command...
   `docker ps`
2. Make a note of the container ID for the running `wordpress` image
3. Execute in container command (replace `[container_id]` with your ID with no brackets)...
   `docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/bash`
4. Change permissions on wp-content folder...
   `chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content`

This should resolve any problems uploading and deleting files via the dashboard for `uploads` and `plugins` locally with docker compose.

Comment: great answer, so with the mounted volumes, if you remove a plugin from the dashboard, does it then also delete the folder in the mounted volume?

Comment: @leo_cape yes it does, and if you install via dashboard it appears in the folder, just be sure to exclude plugins from your git repo

Comment: Thanks - currently its not doing that for my setup, on restart it pulls in the mounted files / plugins etc correctly, but when deleting a plugin in the dashboard it does not delete it from the volume.. any ideas why? Its RW, not read only, it does however also seem to be updating the volume that you referred to in the docker file

Comment: @leo_cape see updated answer above, the last section about permission issues. Is your `uploads.ini` definitely present in your project?

Comment: hmm nope - haven't added that as a volume - I only have wp-content and plugins, do I need to add uploads.ini to get it to write back? I have changed the permissions as per your last section though

Comment: @leo_cape yeah create the uploads.ini before mapping it then docker down and up -d a you should be able to upload/delete via dashboard. This uploads.ini is only for local env, you don't upload it to staging/production

Comment: I see thanks - its actually on staging and prod is where its happening though?

Comment: Bit more context - when restarting it pulls the plugins fine from the bound volume, but it also seems to pull from the 'named' volume it creates as well - so it saves to the named volume, just not to the bound volume

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231423/discussion-between-joshmoto-and-leo-cape).

Comment: when mounting uploads folder this way, I found that it doesn't update your host filesystem with uploads via dashboard. Upon restarting the container, the uploads are lost. Going into the container, I notice the uploads folder is now completely gone. Is there a safe way to mount uploads so this doesn't happen after a restart?

Comment: @FarzadA thats odd, i never has issues with uploads. Have you definitely got your `uploads.ini` mapped too?

Comment: @joshmoto I have a php.ini mapped as such: "./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini" which seems to work, I can see it updated the upload limit. All my mounts work fine except if I'm directly mounting the uploads folder.

Comment: @FarzadA so if you upload a file on your local environment, does the uploaded file appear in the local uploads folder?

Comment: @joshmoto no it does not, I only see an empty uploads folder on my local environment. Then restarting the container causes the upload to disappear from the dashboard and container

Comment: @FarzadA If you not seeing the upload appear in your local uploads folder then the map is not working. Here is screenshot on my local project uploads folder... https://imgur.com/LGpjKV6 - Can you make a gist of your yml file and post it on here?

Comment: @joshmoto Here is a gist with the yml, some env stuff and the ini https://gist.github.com/fafshari/6132ee3d65a8fcf457a4bbf58833c3e7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238411/discussion-between-joshmoto-and-farzad-a).